# Using Selenium RemoteWebDriver behind corporate proxy (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, firewall, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to run Selenium tests on a few remote automation services (Sauce Labs, Browserstack, etc) and run into issues hitting their API through my corporate firewall.

Just a note, the app I'm trying to test is **not** behind this firewall, it is publicly accessible.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
caps.setCapability("platform", "Windows 7");
caps.setCapability("version", "9.0");
caps.setCapability("idleTimeout", "300");
caps.setCapability("name", "Invitation Tests");
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("https://user:key@saucelabs.com), caps);
```

The issue seems to be the plumbing of Selenium interprets the user:key in the url as proxy credentials, so it never leaves our network. Are there any specific tricks to configuring this? It seems to use Apache HttpClient under the hood.

I *think* we're using an NTLM proxy, it seems to use basic auth. It might be the same issue from here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7286

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Code issue that you linked to does indeed appear to be the cause. Note that the issue has been resolved, so you can now inject your own implementation of CommandExecutor when creating a RemoteWebDriver.

Specifically, you would probably do something like this:

- Write a custom implementation of `org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient.Factory` that behaves similarly to the one at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/ApacheHttpClient.java, but allows you to inject the `HttpClient` instance (or `HttpClientFactory` instance, if you want to subclass that). It's quite a simple interface, and a simple implementation to copy, so this should be easy.
- Create an instance of `org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider` with different credentials for the different hosts (see `org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope` for details).
- Use `org.apache.http.impl.HttpClientBuilder` to construct a client with your credential provider.
- Construct an instance of `HttpCommandExecutor`, passing in an instance of your custom factory and injecting your client.
- Construct an instance of `RemoteWebDriver`, passing in the command executor.

Comment: Thanks! That is what i'm going down now. It is ending up being a lot of custom code (complete copies of two of their internal classes with some small changes).

I ran into a separate issue of the NTCredentials not being thread safe, forcing me to ensure only one thread is active at a time. I might have some snippets I can share here shortly. It's not as convenient as I had hoped but I think that is the design.

Comment: I've posted a working implementation of this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846014/using-selenium-remotewebdriver-behind-corporate-proxy/34908953#34908953 for anyone that gets as stuck on it as I did.