# How to setup proxy in AsyncHttpClient?

Tags: asynchttpclient

My app uses AsyncHttpClient library for network operation.My problem is i need to specify the proxy with port in order to connect to remote server.Any ideas to specify it??

Comment: I hope you tried this http://people.apache.org/~simonetripodi/ahc/proxy.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846014/using-selenium-remotewebdriver-behind-corporate-proxy/68985455#68985455

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this

```
 AsyncHttpClientConfig cf = new DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
 .setProxyServer(new ProxyServer.Builder("127.0.0.1", 38080)).build();

 AsyncHttpClient c = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient(cf);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another posibility is to use the standard Java proxy-properties:

```
JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dhttps.proxyHost=<host> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<port> -Dhttp.proxyHost=<host> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port>

AsyncHttpClientConfig config = new DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
   .setUseProxyProperties(true)
   .build();
```