# Selenium - Remote Web Driver - behind corporate firewall

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I need to set an HTTP proxy so that my web driver instance can get out to the Internet.  This post is related, but deals with connecting to the hub / driver through a proxy:

[Using Selenium RemoteWebDriver behind corporate proxy (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263006/using-selenium-remotewebdriver-behind-corporate-proxy-java)

Instead, I need to tell the driver to use the HTTP proxy to get to the Internet.  When passing in the proxy in the desired capabilities, it appears it is ignored and I cannot get out to the Internet.  I am using jbrowserdriver as a remote web driver provider.